# What is the right way of asking someone to give a more detailed explanation of what he just said (or wrote)?

Tags: american-english, usage, british-english, questions

I was told something and now I want to get a more detailed explanation of what the person just said (or wrote).

For example, the person wrote to me:

> The key difference between the two definitions is that valid is a property of sentences and satisfiable is a property of sets of sentences.

Now I want to get that sentence to be explained in more detail to me.

I answered:

> Can you please elaborate?

*Link to that conversation: https://www.reddit.com/r/logic/comments/99geaz/satisfiability_and_validity/e4nyate/*

**Questions:**

1. Is this the right way of asking someone to give a more detailed explanation of what he just said (or wrote)?
2. What are other ways (maybe better, maybe just other) of asking someone to give a more detailed explanation of what he just said (or wrote)?
3. Is there a difference when we speak and when we write? I mean, maybe some variant is better to use when we speak and some is better when we write?

If there is a difference between American English and British English regarding that topic please write that too.

Comment: **Please elaborate** is fine there, especially given the topic of your conversation.  I think "property of sentences" in the reply is intended to mean "a property of *individual* sentences."

Answer (score 2):

**[elaborate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elaborate)** is OK, but it's quite formal. Note that **elaborate** is intransitive: if you want to specify a subject, you have to use the preposition **on**.

One possibility is to use the phrasal verb [expand on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expand-on-sth?q=expand%2Bon).

> Can you please **expand on** that?

According to this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expand%20on%3A%20eng_us_2012%2C%20expand%20on%3A%20eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpand%20on%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpand%20on%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), this phrasal verb is equally common in the US and UK.